# Storing URLs in a JSON and calling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, discord

I am fairly new to programming and currently writing a bot for Discord using the Discord.js library, and when a user enters a command, I would like it to randomly select a link and send it. I have a system like that setup, but all of the links are being stored in an array inside the .js file, and it's very tedious to add new links when I choose to. I am wondering how I could store a list of links inside a JSON and then randomize and send on command. Thank you! :)

Comment: javascript objects have no order, unless you are using `ES6`. Array would be much simpler

Comment: JSON is just a format for passing data around, so if you "store a list of links inside a JSON" you'd still need to maintain the list in almost exactly the same way as you do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a command where I save links into a text file and also a randomizer that takes a random line from that text file and posts in channel.

I'll just give you the code and you can use/play around with it if you want.

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "save")) {
  fs.appendFileSync("links.txt", message.content + "\r\n", encoding = "utf8");
  message.channel.send("Saved.");
}

if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "link")) {
  fs.readFile("links.txt", "utf8", function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    var lines = data.split("\r\n"); //reads it line by line
    var linesTotal = lines.length;
    var lineSend = Math.floor(Math.random() * linesTotal);
    var randomMsg = lines[lineSend];
    message.channel.send(randomMsg);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An array should be fine and you can pick a random index and send it. What difficulties are you having that you want to resort to JSON?

You can just do array.push('link'), and when you have to send the link to the user, you can generate a random number from 0 to the length of the array, pick that number and send it to the user. In fact, I think using JSON will just make things more complicated.

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm having difficulties, but more or less just want to make the code look better by removing a huge array of links. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do my best with that information!